# What does Nietzsche’s “a monstrosity per defectum” mean?

Tags: nietzsche, translation

I was reading through Nietzsche’s The Birth of Tragedy and I came across the phrase -

> In Socrates, instinct becomes the critic, consciousness the creator — a monstrosity per defectum!

As far as I was able to find, it roughly describes the "intrinsic defectiveness in Socrates's ideology" in this context. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Please, read all [previous para](https://books.google.it/books?id=4dW7AQAAQBAJ&pg=PA47): for N, Socrates's *daemon* is an "inner voice" that acts as a critique: it always *dissuades* instead of "inspiring".

Comment: Reading N through Freus, we may say that Socrates' *daemon* is a [sort of Super-ego](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id,_ego_and_super-ego) while N think at the "inner voice" of istinct as a "creatively affirmative force", more akin to Id.

Comment: N. links the life instinct to self affirmation ("all naturalism in morality, that is, all healthy morality, is dominated by an instinct of life." (TI V:4)). i would be at least wary of claiming that S's creativity was deficient by being ruled by his super ego, and the paragraph in question links his criticism to a "divine voice" beyond his own "tremendous intelligence" -- perhaps as much to do with a lack of responsibility as too much! you could see the change as S driving a wedge between instinct and consciousness, as much as inverting their roles: critic is not all there is to creativity.